Is there a sex position that is not allowed in Islam?
I have done my research and found none of the sex positions that are banned in Islam. However, some people say that doggy style is still not liked in Islam; please clarify.

Except anal sex and vaginal sex during menstruation: everything else is halal.
Allah says in the quran: 2:223
"Your wives are a place of sowing of seed for you, so come to your place of cultivation however you wish and put forth [righteousness] for yourselves. And fear Allah and know that you will meet Him. And give good tidings to the believers".
Iman Ibn kathir explained:
The Reason behind revealing Allah's Statement: "Your Wives are a Tilth for You.
Allah said:
نِسَآؤُكُمْ حَرْثٌ لَّكُمْ
(Your wives are a tilth for you,)
Ibn `Abbas commented, "Meaning the place of pregnancy." Allah then said:
فَأْتُواْ حَرْثَكُمْ أَنَّى شِئْتُمْ
(...so go to your tilth, when or how you will,) meaning, wherever you wish from the front or from behind, as long as sex takes place in one valve (the female sexual organ), as the authentic Hadiths have indicated.
For instance, Al-Bukhari recorded that Ibn Al-Munkadir said that he heard Jabir say that the Jews used to claim that if one has sex with his wife from behind (in the vagina) the offspring would become cross-eyed. Then, this Ayah was revealed:
نِسَآؤُكُمْ حَرْثٌ لَّكُمْ فَأْتُواْ حَرْثَكُمْ أَنَّى شِئْتُمْ
(Your wives are a tilth for you, so go to your tilth, when or how you will,)
AND HE GIVES VERY LONG EXPLANATION IN HIS TAFSIR, YOU CAN READ ON YOUR OWN IF YOU WANT.
SO EVERY POSITION AND EVERYTHING IS PERMISSIBLE EXCEPT ANAL SEX AND VAGINAL SEX DURING MENSTRUATION

According to Shia Fiqh as far as I have seen:

All positions are allowed, as long as doesn't hurt the couples ...

Anal intercourse is badly discouraged, some scholar assume it Haram but most only consider it as Makrouh (discouraged)

Oral sex is allowed as long as the semen is not swallowed as it is Najis (unclean)

the man is allowed to enter his wife's vagina nothing other than his own body limbs


PS. if this is going to yield into pregnancy, also consult e.g. here and here (use a translator if required)
